# Calculating the angular direction from velocity

Tags: javascript, geometry, 2d, physics, trigonometry

I'm trying to calculate the angular direction of a projectile, knowing it's X and Y velocity I can find the magnitude of its movement, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my mind around getting the angular direction (in radians) that it is moving...

I assume there is a tan or a sin involved, but I'm a bit clueless otherwise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in `Math.atan2`.

Given an `x` and `y` around the origin, it will return the angle. E.g.

```
Math.atan2(  0,   1) === 0;
Math.atan2(0.5, 0.5) === Math.PI / 4;
```

It does take the direction into account, so you don't have to worry about `1 / 1` or `-1 / -1` (which would normally result in the same angle).

Answer (score 0):

tan-1(y/x)

Don't know if you're taking gravity into consideration and so.